# (Xcode 6 Swift Language) saving users data (username, userEmail, userPassword) and send it to database

Tags: swift, database, registration

I'm making an IOS app for iPhone that required users to register. I want to send data to a service sites and then record it on database, but i only know how to save it locally, by using this code:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(userEmail, forKey:"userEmail");
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(userEmail, forKey:"userPasswoed");

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize();
```

So the question is how can I save the users data and then send it to a service sites and record it in database (using the Swift language)?

Comment: You should never store passwords in UserDefaults - that's what the keychain is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By database, I'm guessing you mean something like parse. You can register for Parse at parse.com and go through the steps in quick start to set your app up. Parse creates a user class for you then you can create a variable for the username, email and password and send that data to parse using the pfuser class. Once you have done all of that, this is the code you can use to set those properties and send them to parse.

```
let user = PFUser()
user.username = username
user.email = userEmail
user.password = password
```